# Proving a sequence of piecewise continuous functions in $(C[0,1], d_1)$ is Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Denote $f_n(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & x \leq \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}\\
\frac{1}{2}-\frac{n}{4}+\frac{n}{2}x & \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n} < x \leq \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}, \quad n\geq 2\\
1 & x > \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}
\end{cases}$.

We have $|f_m(x) - f_n(x)| \leq \frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{n}{m})$ with equality at $x=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{m}$ or $x=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{m}$ for $m>n$. Now, to obtain the Cauchy condition where $m,n>K$ we have $|f_m(x) - f_n(x)|< \epsilon$. So the part I am stuck on is turning this inequality for $\epsilon$ into an inequality for $m$ or $n$ to get $K$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume, that $x_0>\frac{1}{2}$, then we can find such $K$ that $x_0>\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}$ when $n>K$. Now if we take $n,m>K$, then $f_m(x_0) - f_n(x_0)=1-1=0.$

Analogically for $x_0<\frac{1}{2}$.